# Existence of path under weight and value budgets

Tags: graphs, np-hard

Consider the following problem:

> Input: An undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, each edge has a non-negative weight $w_i$ and a non-negative value $v_i$. There are two vertices to represent start point $s$ and end point $t$. We are also given two values $W,V$.
>
> Decide whether there is a simple path from $s$ to $t$ with total weight at most $W$ and total value at most $V$.

How do I show that the problem is NP-hard by reduction from PARTITION?

Comment: What did you try? Consider encoding the decision to put an item in one or another part by different choices of arcs in an st-path.

Comment: I have tried to construct a complete graph, so that I can represent every combination of choices of integers, but since both constraints are at most, this graph will return a yes instance even if the partition instance is no

Comment: Make the graph more restricted. Try to do the reduction first for a single item, then for two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea of the reduction; I'll let you fill in the details.

We are given an instance of the partition problem, consisting of numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ summing to $S$. We construct a (non-simple) graph on the vertex set $s = v_0,\ldots,v_n = t$. For $i=1,\ldots,n$, there are two edges from $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$: one with weight $x_i$ and value $0$, and one with weight $0$ and value $x_i$. Our target weight and value are both $S/2$.

I'll let you figure out why this works, and convert it to a simple graph.

Comment: We can simply divide $v_i$ to $v_i$ and $v_i'$. Then, the edges from $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$ and $v_i'$ should be $x_i\;/\;0$, and edges from $v_{i-1}'$ to $v_i$ and $v_i'$ should be $0\;/\;x_i$.

Comment: Right, that's the idea.